# TinyMCE file_picker_callback trying to send axios request but no cookies

Tags: express, cookies, axios, tinymce, middleware

The problem i'm currently facing is that I make an axios Post multipart/form-data request that contains a image. This comes from file_picker_callback from the TinyMCE Editor Component.

```
<Editor
     onInit={(evt, editor) => (editorRef.current = editor)}
     initialValue={service?.description || ""}
     init={{
         apiKey: tinyApiKey,
         height: 1000,
         menubar: false,
         plugins: ["image", "link"],
         toolbar:
             "h1 h2 h3 | image link | formatselect | " +
             "bold | alignleft aligncenter " +
             "alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | " +
             "removeformat | help",
         content_style:
             "body { font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px }",
         images_upload_url: 
                  `${process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL}/api/upload`,
         file_picker_callback: (callback, value, meta) => {
                  const input = document.createElement("input");
                  input.setAttribute("type", "file");
                  input.setAttribute("name", "image");
                  input.setAttribute("accept", "image/*");

                  input.onchange = () => {
                    const file = input.files[0];
                    const formData = new FormData();
                    formData.append("file", file);

                    axios
                    .post(`${process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL}/api/upload`,
                            formData)
                          .then((response) => {
                            const editor = window.tinymce.activeEditor;
                            const img = `<figure className="img-container"><img src="${response.data.location}" alt="descriptive"/></figure>`;
                            editor.insertContent(img);
                            callback(response.data.location);
                          })
                          .catch((error) => {
                            console.log(error);
                          });
                      };
                      input.click();
                    },
                  }}
                />
```

The backend routing contains 2 middlewares, the first one the authMiddleware and the second one, multer, my request cannot get past authMiddleware.

Router:

```
const protect = require("../middleware/authMiddleware");
const { upload } = require("../utils/fileUpload");

router.post("/", protect, upload.single("file"), uploadImage);
```

authMiddleware.js :

```
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const User = require("../models/userModel");
const asyncHandler = require("express-async-handler");

const protect = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const token = req.cookies.token;

    // Valiadate
    if (!token) {
      res.status(401);
      throw new Error("Not authorized, please log in");
    }

    // Verify
    const verified = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);

    const user = await User.findById(verified.id).select("-password");

    if (!user) {
      res.status(404);
      throw new Error("User not found");
    }
    req.user = user;
    next();
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(401);
    throw new Error("Not authorized, please log in");
  }
});

module.exports = protect;
```

uploadController.js :

```
const asyncHandler = require("express-async-handler");
const { fileSizeFormatter } = require("../utils/fileUpload");

const uploadImage = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  fileData = {
    fileName: req.file.originalname,
    filePath: req.file.path,
    fileType: req.file.mimetype,
    fileSize: fileSizeFormatter(req.file.size, 2),
  };

  res.status(201).json({
    location: `${req.protocol}://${req.hostname}:5000/${req.file.path}`,
  });
});

module.exports = {
  uploadImage,
};
```

I checked console and the error is Not Authorized, please log in which is from authMiddleware, i also checked that the request doesn't send any cookie. I also have:
`axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;`

I checked console and the error is Not Authorized, please log in which is from authMiddleware, i also checked that the request doesn't send any cookie. I also have:
`axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;`

Comment: You should see what the actual error is - in your authMiddleware.js catch block try `console.error(error)` before `throw new Error` - this should will tell you what the actual error is.